# Difference between array of pointers and a 2-D array

Tags: arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
int *m[10], n[10][10];
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
m[4] = a;
```

Which of the following would give error upon trying to print the value and why? (Assume even n[10][10] to be initialized appropriately)

```
1) m[2][4]
2) n[2]
3) m[3]
```

(PS: Please explain in detail)

Comment: You need to add more information; are you trying to print out values from those indices, set something to them, or what?  Are you creating any other memory that any of the pointers in m point to?  There just isn't enough information given.

Comment: I'm trying to print the values.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler won't complain when you try to create each of these things, but you likely won't get the print out values you expect.

`int *m[10]` is creating an array of 10 pointers to ints.  This could point to 10 different ints, or (as I suspect you are thinking) it could point to 10 "arrays" of ints.  The problem here is context (it often is in C); we don't know exactly what you are trying to do.  An `int*` points to a memory location that holds an `int`.  This might be a single `int` or it might be an array of `ints`.  Your code doesn't have any other setup information - not malloc'ing or setting a pointer equal to the address of an int - so we don't know.  When you print it out we don't know what you might get, as the memory doesn't seem to be created yet (according to the code we see here).

The n[10][10] is (on most systems) going to be set automatically to a 10x10 array initialized to 0 - but we can't count on that.  Regardless, we don't know what is going to print out.  If you print out using `printf` you could print the value of the memory address that n[2] holds.  Probably not what you want.  If you don't print it out as a pointer, but instead use the %d modifier of `printf`, the compiler will likely show a warning but will allow it.  What prints out will the an address interpreted as an integer.  Probably not what you want either.

Printing out m[3] is the same issue as with n[2] concerning whether it prints an int or a pointer.  However, (possibly) unlike n m's memory doesn't appear (from your code) to ever be setup.  It will likely (on most systems) print out a 0 as it is probably set to a null pointer by default.  Once again though, I don't know that we can count on that.

People are often taught that with C there are multiple ways to do things - and that is true.  But what they aren't usually taught is there is a proper context to do most things, or a when to use one method or another.  Largely the contexts are defined by whether we are using compile time or run-time allocated memory.  You need to read up on memory management in C and learn more about what the Stack and Heap are for before you will really understand the differences.